# Pivot a table using SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

i need to pivot a table in SQLite but the problem is that there's no pivot function.
Using this table named Subject as an example:

| Subject_id | Subject_Name | Subject_Semester |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Calculus | 5 |
| 261 | Chemistry | 4 |
| 897 | Biology | 4 |

the result that i want to get is:

| Subject_Semester | Subject1 | Subject2 | Subject3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Chemistry | Biology | Null |
| 5 | Calculus | Null | Null |

checking some solutions i have tried to do this

```
Select Subject_semester,
        max(case  when Subject_Name=Subject_Name then Subject_Name else Null end) as Subject1
        max(case  when Subject_Name=Subject_Name then Subject_Name else Null end) as Subject2
        max(case  when Subject_Name=Subject_Name then Subject_Name else Null end) as Subject3
 from Subject 
 group by Subject_semester;
```

as expected i get this result where only one subject appears and repeats in every column

| Subject_Semester | Subject1 | Subject2 | Subject3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Chemistry | Chemistry | Chemistry |
| 5 | Calculus | Calculus | Calculus |

Is there a way to get my desired result?,also i have tried using this SQLite [extension](https://github.com/jakethaw/pivot_vtab) but i am not allowed to install it on my work computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a row number to each subject, grouped by *Subject_Semester*, you can directly retrieve the corresponding subjects by semester exploiting this generated index value:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Subject_Semester) AS idx
    FROM tab
)
SELECT Subject_Semester,
       MAX(CASE WHEN idx = 1 THEN Subject_Name ELSE NULL END) AS Subject1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN idx = 2 THEN Subject_Name ELSE NULL END) AS Subject2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN idx = 3 THEN Subject_Name ELSE NULL END) AS Subject3
FROM cte 
GROUP BY Subject_semester;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k44jbX61a9MUhHoFddmm3T/1).